# How can my Rig slow down that much in short period?

Tags: mining, ether, difficulty, rig

I wonder why my Rig used to mine 1Ether in 24h and now it takes up to 38h for 1. I have moved the Rig to another place, could that be the reason? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is normal and due to the mining difficulty rising in response to the additional hashpower being pointed at Ethereum.

As Ethereum becomes more and more profitable to mine, the additional miners make it harder (more difficult) for other miners in the network to find shares and earn eth from pools or from solo mining.

Comment: Ok thanks! So it doesn't matter which city or country ur in right? Or does it matter if the area has more miners in it?

Comment: No, that does not matter. The Ethereum difficulty is a globale network value.